# Handling async functions in Swift

Tags: swift, swiftui, async-await, core-location, ibeacon

I'm trying to implement CLMonitor to monitor my iBeacons.

```swift
@MainActor class BeaconHandler: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = BeaconHandler()
    
    private let locationManager: CLLocationManager
    private var monitor: CLMonitor?
    
    private init() {
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        Task(priority: .high) {
            self.monitor = await CLMonitor("BeaconHandler")
        }
    }
    
    func addToMonitor(identifier: String, major: Int, minor: Int) {
        Task {
            let beaconCondition = CLMonitor.BeaconIdentityCondition(uuid: UUID(uuidString: identifier)!, major: UInt16(major), minor: UInt16(minor))
            
            await self.monitor?.add(beaconCondition, identifier: identifier, assuming: .unsatisfied)
        }
    }
    
    func removeFromMonitor(identifier: String) {
        Task {
            await self.monitor?.remove(identifier)
        }
    }
    
    func getEventStateFor(identifier: String) async -> CLMonitor.Event.State {
        if self.monitor == nil {
            return .unmonitored
        }
        
        if let monitoredRecord = await self.monitor!.record(for: identifier) {
            return monitoredRecord.lastEvent.state
        }
        
        return .unmonitored
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is to add beacons to the monitor, and get current state of its beacon every second to display using SwiftUI. But, I am not sure if it's the best apporach to initialise CLMonitor, since addToMonitor gets called before the initialisation of CLMonitor.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Get rid of all those floating Task so you can actually call the functions in order.

Comment: Note, if you are not publishing anything (@Published), there is no point in having a `ObservableObject`.

Comment: @loremipsum you mean async functions? I kinda confused how to initialise `CLMonitor` then..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it seems you are trying to "pull" the state of the Beacon. I would advise against that. The `CLMonitor` has an async sequence called `events` that can be set up to "observe" changes to the state of the beacon.

According to this [wwdc video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10147/) the latest state will only become populated with the latest value if you observe the change. So you should start observing as soon as your application starts.

A more general example of how this would work:

```
// add the async Stream observer
do{
    for try await event in await monitor.events{
        if let monitoredRecord = await self.monitor.record(for: identifier) {
            let lastEvent = monitoredRecord.lastEvent
            // manipulate the model according to the last Event
        }
    }
} catch{
    
}
```